# afplay Error: AudioFileOpen failed (-43)

Tags: c

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char folderPath[1024];
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < (strlen(argv[0]) - 7); i++) {
        folderPath[i] = argv[0][i];
    }
    printf("Command: afplay %ssong.mp3\n", folderPath);
    system("afplay %ssong.mp3", folderPath);
    return 0;
}
```

All Output:

```
Command: afplay /Users/carloabelli/Desktop/FUNNY/song.mp3
Error: AudioFileOpen failed (-43)
```

When I run the command from terminal it works perfectly. I was wondering what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system()` does not use a format string. It takes the whole command as a literal string. Use `sprintf()` to format your command into a buffer and then send that buffer to system.

```
char buf[1024];
snprintf(buf, 1024, "afplay %ssong.mp3", folderPath);
system(buf);
```

or something along these lines.