# Python- What does 'Error: AudioFileOpen failed ('wht?')' mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run this code but it causes the following error: Error: AudioFileOpen failed ('wht?'). So here's my code-it's running on a Mac and with a folder of mp3 files if that is any help:

```
import os
def randomShuffleSongFromFolder(folderPath):
    try:
        music = os.listdir(folderPath)
    except:
        print('Error-Music folder not found')
        exit()
    random.shuffle(music)
    music.remove('.DS_Store')
    print(folderPath)
    print(music)
    for song in music:
        os.system('afplay "' + song + '"')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(os.listdir('/Users/isaac_lims_macbook_air/Desktop/davidMusic'))
randomShuffleSongFromFolder('/Users/isaac_lims_macbook_air/Desktop/MusicExample/')
```

Any help is welcomed and greatly thanked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this (from your question):

```
for song in music:
    os.system('afplay "' + song + '"')
```

and remember what `music` contains: a list of file names (e.g. `"Adele - Hello.mp3"`). When you pass them to `afplay` you aren't telling it which directory to look in. (Note that the error message is not coming from Python, but rather from `afplay` itself; e.g. see [this other question where the same command is called from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491271/afplay-error-audiofileopen-failed-43).)

Try using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.join) to include the directory, e.g.

```
import os.path

# Assuming folderPath is being passed into the containing function as above
for song in music:
    songPath = os.path.join(folderPath, song)
    os.system('afplay "{}"'.format(songPath))
```

That way `afplay` will receive an absolute path like `"/Users/you/Desktop/Music/Adele - Hello.mp3"`.